# merging two if else statements pertaining to user login state

Tags: php, facebook

morning everyone!

i need some help in merging two if statements pertaining to the current users login states and creating a third one.

there are 3 states:

1. user is logged in using the facebook
   connect option
2. user is logged in using the website
   login form
3. user is not logged in using either

i have been able to draft the conditional statements for both 1) and 2) which do not work properly.

it has yet to be perfected.

if the user is logged in using the facebook connect option the conditional statement does not stop at 1) it carries on to 2) thus producing the error **Undefined index: uid**.

this happens because the index uid is only created when the user is logged in using the website form.

i have no idea of implementing 3) at this moment!

i would appreciate any help in advancing this code.

thanks in advance.

```
<?php
// if logged in using fb connect
if ($user) {
      echo "fb";
// proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated
} else {
// proceed knowing you require user login and/or authentication
echo "this is shown to a user who has not logged in";
} 

// if logged in using login form
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
// proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated
  echo "kite"; } 
// proceed knowing you require user login and/or authentication
else { 
echo "this is shown to a user who has not logged in";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, heres a crack at this:

```
if (isset($user)){ // use isset() to avoid undefined index warning ..
    echo "fb";
} elseif($_SESSION['uid']){
    echo "kite";
}else{
   // Anonymous user
   echo "this is shown to a user who has not logged in";
}
```

Technically, the last else would not be needed if you had a variable holding the logged-in state. If your last ifelse returns false, you know the user is anonymous but in this example the last else is needed so the script doesn't echo the anonymous message to all conditions.

Be aware that users can logged on to facebook can still have $_SESSION uid set though.
You would need to put the condition you want to have prevalence as the first to be evaluated or add a condition that disallows both fb and $_SESSION being set, I don't really know what your intention is for this.

Comment: its not possible for the user to be logged in on both

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the check for `uid` in an `else if` instead of another `if`. The following code should fix the problem:

```
<?php
    // if logged in using fb connect
    if ($user) {
          echo "fb";
    // proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated
    } // if logged in using login form
    elseif (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    // proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated
          echo "kite"; 
    } 
    // proceed knowing you require user login and/or authentication
    else { 
    // proceed knowing you require user login and/or authentication
          echo "this is shown to a user who has not logged in";
    } 

?>
```

Comment: else if is not recommended, preferable to use elseif. Taken from [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php):  Note: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.

Comment: @stefgosselin: +1. Thanks for increasing my knowledge. I have a different background, so have been using it since it has been working, as I have always been using {} instead of :

Comment: Pleasure my friend. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($user)
{
  echo "fb";
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['uid']))
{
  echo "kite";
}
else
{
  echo "this is shown to a user who has not logged in";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($user || isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
  echo $user?('fb'.(isset($_SESSION['uid'])?' AND kite':'')):'kite';
}else{
  echo 'this is shown to a user who has not logged in';
}
```